# Is there a formula to calculate & format h:mm:ss into mmm:ss?

Tags: excel

I have a list of total time formatted as "h:mm:ss" (ex 2:59:52), but I need it to reflect "mmm:ss" (ex 179:52). I haven't found help online for my specific challenge. Everything I have found so far drops only the hour, without adding it into the minute. For example, it takes 2:59:52 and changes it to 59:52, which is not my goal.  My goal is to take 2 hours 59 minutes and 52 seconds (2:59:52) and convert it to 179 minutes and 52 seconds (179:52). Is this even possible in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

**[mm]:ss**

For example:

[image]

Or some other equivalent format